# Where does this argument showing there are uncountably many TMs fail?

Tags: computability, fake-proofs, turing-machines

This argument comes up once every while on Lambda the Ultimate. I want to know where the flaw is.

*Take a countable number of TMs all generating different bitstreams. Construct a Cantor TM which runs every nth TM upto the nth bit and outputs the reversed bit.*

*Now I have established there are uncountably many TMs.*

(The argument is that every bitstream is a unique real in the set [0,1]. Since every TM can be seen to be represented by that real, we can use Cantor's construction to prove that there are uncountably many TMs.)

Where does it go wrong?

Comment: One of the assumptions you are implicitly making is that the enumeration avoids (possibly different) TMs printing the same string **and** is computable. If anything at all, the proof shows that such an enumeration can not exist.

Comment: I think we can liberally assume that such an enumeration exists. At minimum, we know we can create the bitstreams for 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc.

Comment: Further problems: What is the nth digit inverted if the output is shorter than n digits? Finally, your enumeration has to ensure that each of the Turing machines actually terminates (or at least prints enough digits without running into an infinite loop before). I am not convinced that such an enumeration is indeed possible (in a computable way).

Comment: "Construct a Cantor TM which runs every $n$-th TM up to the $n$-th bit and outputs the reversed bit."  How?  How would you construct this Cantor TM that knows how to simulate each of the TMs on a given infinite list?  If you try to make this part precise, you'll see that you can't do it.  Note that for the proof by contradiction to show that there are uncountably many TMs (of a particular type), the initial list has to be *arbitrary* (except for the restriction to that type)... it's not enough to choose a particular list, like TMs generating 1, 1/2, 1/3, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are uncountably many Turing machines, if you allow them to use oracles (which are real numbers, really).

But if you disallow that, then the only way that this process gives back a Turing machine is if the enumeration itself is computable. So what you have shown is that the set of Turing machines is not computable (albeit it is recursively enumerable, but that is not enough).

This "liberal assumption" is the only assumption that you make which does not imply "most infinite sets related mathematics is inconsistent", by Occam razor arguments alone it shows that the assumption might be *a bit **too** liberal* after all.

As for the suggestion that we make an enumeration for enumerating the rational numbers, sure, you just get (more or less) an irrational number. Showing that *one* countable set doesn't include all the Turing machines is not a contradiction.

Comment: The rational number example was too trivial, I agree. Somewhere your answer leaves me with a bad taste regarding what real numbers I can algebraically construct in constructive mathematics. I'll ponder about it somewhat more but I am out of my league here. Thanks.

Comment: There's a reason why computable analysis is so much harder than classical analysis, and why it requires meticulous attention to details.

Comment: I don't find your answer very satisfying either. If I label your alineas 'a' to 'd'. Let's not discuss 'a', irrelevant. 'b' is an argument "the conclusion is absurd, therefore the construction is flawed", so is 'c'. I would like to have a more direct refutal. I think I do not understand your reasoning in 'd', rational numbers are a subset of the reals, I don't feel it matters that the construction only uses rational numbers as long as it gives back a Cantor argument.

Maybe I miss something, but I am not satisfied yet. I would really like a more direct refutal.

Comment: (b) is fine, that is the idea behind proof by contradiction, if the conclusion is indeed an absurd, then the premise was false. (c) fine, fix an enumeration of the sentences in the language of arithmetic, and take an enumeration of Turing machines such that the $n$-th machine calculates that the $n$-th bit is $0$ if and only the $n$-th sentence is true in $\Bbb N$; the diagonal Turing machine gives you a "computable" definition of the truth, which contradicts Tarski's theorem. (d) simply illustrates that for a fixed enumeration the diagonal argument yields no contradictions.

Comment: Thanks. I will look up your direct argument. I think your reasoning regarding 'd' is flawed. I cannot use Cantor's argument on rational numbers since the construction of a diagonal number simply gives back an element outside of the set. (Whereas here I try to give an informal diagonal argument given a subset returning a diagonal outside the subset but within the set of reals.)

Comment: (d) was only brought up because you suggested enumerating the rational numbers. The idea is that enumerating *one* proper subset, does not mean that you can do that for *every* subset. If you consider the enumeration of the real numbers $x_n$ being only $1$ at the $n$-th point, then you obtain the string $000\ldots$ as the diagonal string. Does it mean that the natural numbers are suddenly uncountable? No, it does not. And (d) was brought up to show that enumerating the rationals in a computable manner, does not mean that you can enumerate the TMs in a computable manner as well.

Comment: Ah. Hinges on too lousy and concise question. The assumption is that there are uncountably many TMs (since there are uncountably many bitstreams), and the rest of the question is supposed to be read as a proof by contradiction. So you assumed I started off with a countable set, whereas I meant that as the start of the proof by contradiction. Never mind. Should be filed under: Too sloppy a question.

Comment: Again, the part in (d) is specifically aimed at the point that "Oh, we can pick *this* enumeration, and the diagonal TM exists!" is not a real counter-argument. I don't think the question itself is that sloppy.

Comment: Ah well. Thanks. I didn't know this about Cantor's diagonal construction. I thought the objection was I end up with an element outside of the set, whereas you meant I cannot pick specific enumerations. Apart from that, sorry for insisting but a guy on LtU makes pretty wild claims and I need the most 'stupid' counterargument to all his claims since he is very insistent. At least I learned something.

Answer (score 3):

There are uncountably many countable sets of Turing machines, and only countably many of these can be enumerated by a Turing machine (since there are, in fact, only countably many Turing machines). So for most such subsets, your Cantor TM can't exist.

Comment: Your argument is based on "Have faith in math, it cannot exist." Unsatisfying. I do agree I'ld need to give a construction, though.

Comment: @Marco: I don't follow. Are you disagreeing that there are uncountably many countable sets of Turing machines or what?

Comment: Look, if the argument were true, it blows up a part of math (Uncountable TMs). Your reasoning is "If we have faith in math, only countably many TMs exist, then the construction cannot exist." I agree that there are only countable many TMs, but it's somewhat cyclic reasoning, and I would like to have a more 'constructive' argument that simply blocks the construction.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here. To begin, I'll assume that by a Turing Machine we mean a Turing Machine with unary input alphabet $\{ \mathsf{1} \}$, and tape alphabet $\{ \mathsf{1} , \mathsf{-} \}$, where $\mathsf{-}$ is the blank symbol. The natural number $k$ is inputted into such a Turing Machine in the usual unary manner: $\overbrace{\mathsf{1}\cdots\mathsf{1}}^{k\text{ times}}$.

To view such a Turing Machine as generating a bitstream, we'll say that the $k$th bit generated by $M_n$ is $1$, if $M_n$ halts reading a $\mathsf{1}$ on input $k$, and is $0$ if $M_n$ halts reading a blank on that same input.

Now take your enumeration $\{ M_0, M_1 , \ldots \}$ of all these Turing machines, and devise a Turing machine $M_*$ so that on input $k$ it outputs the reverse of whatever $M_k$ outputs on input $k$. Now, if $M_* = M_k$ for some $k$, then we have the following

- if the $k$th bit outputted by $M_k$ is $1$, then the $k$th bit outputted by $M_*$ is $1$, and so by our description the $k$th bit outputted by $M_k$ is $0$, and similarly,
- if the $k$th bit outputted by $M_k$ if $0$, then the $k$th bit outputted by $M_k$ is $1$.

But there is a third possibility that hasn't even been counted upon, and that is that $M_k$ *may not halt* on input $k$. If $M_k$ does not halt on input $k$, then we say nothing of what $M_*$ does. In fact, when we say that a TM $M$ uses the output of another TM $M^\prime$ to determine its output, we generally mean that $M$ simulates $M^\prime$ on the desired input (or that $M^\prime$ is a "subroutine" of $M$). If $M_k$ does not halt on input $k$, then $M_*$ will also not halt on this input. Notice that we've alleviated the supposed contradiction to the countability of TMs quite nicely.

But, you may ask, what if we assume that our enumeration is set up so that for each $k$ the TM $M_k$ halts on input $k$? Well, you're not going to get *all* the TMs in this manner, because there are TMs that do not halt on any input (and so cannot be part of this enumeration). Also, for each $k$ there would be infinitely many TMs that halt only on input $k$.  So this route is a bit of a non-starter.

But let's try to be even more generous and suppose that $\{ M_0, M_1 , \ldots \}$ is an enumeration of *all* TMs that halt on *all* inputs. Now $M_*$ also halts on all inputs, and we appear to have arrived at a contradiction. But to what?

Well, we now get into a matter that has been overlooked. In order for $M_*$ to simulate any of the infinitely many $M_k$ it must be that the enumeration is given to $M_*$ in such a way that it can algorithmically convert the input $k$ into a description of $M_k$. So our beginning enumeration is not arbitrary, but must be *computable*. The contradiction we run into now is that there is no *computable* enumeration of all TMs which halt on all inputs.

Comment: The implicit assumption in the question is that you start of with TMs which don't halt.

Comment: @Marco Read the last couple paragraphs.

Comment: I think the argument is more readable if you show that for each TM which calculates the k-th bit you can construct a TM which outputs an infinite stream of bits. Looks like I missed that in first glancing over your construction; I assumed it simply didn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this argument. If you want to use contradiction to prove the set of all TM's is uncountable you must first assume there is an enumeration of all TM's. This "proof" only assumes we have a countably infinite set of TM's with unique output. There are a lot of such sets. One such is the set of TM's that output the binary representation of an unique rational number. Using a diagonal argument to prove there is a TM that outputs the representation of an irrational number proves nothing about the size of this set of rational output TM's.

The argument fails even if we assume we have an enumeration of all TM's. To make things simpler, assume we have an enumeration of all [busy beavers](http://www.drivenbycode.com/turing-machines-and-the-busy-beaver-game/) (BB) and want to prove there is an uncountable number of BB's. There are $((4*(n+1))^{2n}$ possible 2 symbol BB's with $n$ states. We can encode all $n$ states of a specific machine into a natural number. Once we specify an encoding we can enumerate all the valid numbers that encode a BB. This gives us an enumeration of all BB's.

The argument says to construct a BB that runs the BB encoded as $n$ for $n$ steps and reverses the output. A BB has to output something on every step. If the BB halts before step $n$ we can assume it outputs $0$ on step $n$.

This is the second major flaw in this argument. There is no way to construct such a BB. We are assuming on step $n$ this BB outputs the opposite of the $nth$ BB. Obviously, no BB can emulate the first $n$ steps of another BB in less than $n$ steps. This magical BB would have to know in advance what to output on step $n$.

The argument still fails if we try to construct a BB that outputs the anti-diagonal. We can construct such a BB for the first $n$ machines. A BB that outputs the anti-diagonal for all BB's would have to have an infinite number of states. By definition, a BB can only have a finite number of states.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a countable number of constructible reals. The Cantor TM only proves that any enumeration can be extended with an extra element. Since it didn't start of with a bijection between the natural numbers and the reals, the construction doesn't prove that that bijection doesn't exist.

(I answered my own question by summarizing the answers.)